# GitLab CI executes only one job

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm using GitLab.com free account and have installed GitLab-Runner on my Windows PC. For some reason GitLab CI is executing only one job from my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

To test it I've created simple `.gitlab-ci.yml` file with two jobs.

```
job1:
    script:
        - echo 1

job2:
    script:
        - echo 2
```

When I commit it to repository only job1 is executed. I've check with CI lint, file is valid. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that problem was with encoding of `.gitlab-ci.yml` file. Initially it was encoded as `UCS-2 LE BOM`. After converting it to `UTF-8` both jobs were recognized.